# Eclipse ADT não funciona

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
[2015-05-23 11:29:54 - Jokenpo] /home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/Jokenpo/res/values/styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-05-23 11:29:54 - Jokenpo] 
[2015-05-23 11:29:54 - Jokenpo] /home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/Jokenpo/res/values-v11/styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-05-23 11:29:54 - Jokenpo] 
[2015-05-23 11:29:54 - Jokenpo] /home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/Jokenpo/res/values-v14/styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2015-05-23 11:29:54 - Jokenpo] 
[2015-05-23 11:29:57 - Jokenpo] /home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/Jokenpo/res/values/styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-05-23 11:29:57 - Jokenpo] 
[2015-05-23 11:29:57 - Jokenpo] /home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/Jokenpo/res/values-v11/styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-05-23 11:29:57 - Jokenpo] 
[2015-05-23 11:29:57 - Jokenpo] /home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/Jokenpo/res/values-v14/styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2015-05-23 11:29:57 - Jokenpo]
```

Esse é erro que está sendo enviado ao console do Eclipse ADT toda vez que crio um projeto Android!

Além disso, o código inteiro do projeto fica cheio de erros e bugs.

Comment: No seu AndroidManifest.xml qual é o valor que está atribuído a `android:targetSdkVersion`?

Answer (score 1):

Talvez isto ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light

É mais ou menos assim:

Abaixe a biblioteca addCompat aqui:

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

vá até `Windows -> Android SDK Manager` na tab `extras` selecione `Android Support Library` e confirme a instalação. Depois disso verifique se foi instalado com:

```
android-sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat
```

Adicione a referencia no seu projeto:

1. Clique com o botão direito no seu projeto.
2. Selecione propriedades.
3. Clique em 'add...' abaixo de add biblioteca.
4. Selecione a lib suportada
5. Limpe e construa seu projeto